# Installing mobsf but "pip install -r requirements.txt" takes too much time

Tags: python, installation, pip

I am trying to install in the command line of linux (WSL) following this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dnn2uHv7wwY but when I use the command
pip install -r requirements.txt but it takes too much time to determine which version is compatible with other requirements in every package
What is going wrong and how can I reduce the time of pip installation

pip version pip 22.0.2

My requirements file is :

```
Django>=3.1.5
lxml>=4.6.2
rsa>=4.7
biplist>=1.0.3
requests>=2.25.1
bs4>=0.0.1
colorlog>=4.7.2
macholib>=1.14
whitenoise>=5.2.0
waitress>=1.4.4;platform_system=='Windows'
gunicorn>=20.0.4;platform_system!='Windows'
psutil>=5.8.0
shelljob>=0.6.2
asn1crypto>=1.4.0
oscrypto>=1.2.1
distro>=1.5.0
IP2Location==8.9.0
lief>=0.12.1
http-tools>=2.1.1
libsast>=1.5.1
pdfkit>=0.6.1
google-play-scraper>=0.1.2
androguard==3.4.0a1
apkid==2.1.4
quark-engine==22.10.1
frida==15.2.2
tldextract==3.4.0
openstep-parser==1.5.4
svgutils==0.3.4
# For semgrep & mitmproxy
ruamel.yaml==0.16.13 # pyup: ignore
click==8.0.1 # pyup: ignore
decorator==4.4.2 # pyup: ignore
```

Comment: What exactly is your issue? Is the runtime too long?

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal Yes the problem is thati ist takes too much time to finish

Comment: It seems you are trying to check the versions of 32 packages and install them if required. If many packages are missing of course it is taking some time to finish.

Comment: Is there any other way to reduce the time without ignoring the required packages?

Comment: why didn't you just let the installation run instead of asking a question & waiting for an answer?

Comment: I let the installation run 9 hours and after that it crashed

Comment: Have you tried running with the `-v` flag: it will show more detailed logs and you can see what steps are taking longer.